nginx subsequent cache updates
I have nginx cache and cached upstream response. After a while, upstream response status
for the same resource changes to 404 with Cache-control no-cache. After that nginx serves STALE status and old 200 response. Is it possible to have proxy_cache_background_update on; but if response has changed to non 200 status - return that response instead of stale cache.
#default location
proxy_cache my_cache;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
proxy_cache_background_update on;
proxy_cache_use_stale updating error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_429;
proxy_cache_lock on;

